# Strange behavior of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, pass-by-reference

Following results are very interesting and I am having difficulty understanding them. Basically I have a class which has an int:

```
class TestClass{
public:
    int test;
    TestClass() { test = 0; };
    TestClass(int _test) { test = _test; };
    ~TestClass() { /*do nothing*/ };
};
```

A test function which accepts a pointer of TestClass

```
void testFunction1(TestClass *ref){
    delete ref;
    TestClass *locTest = new TestClass();
    ref = locTest;
    ref->test = 2;
    cout << "test in testFunction1: " << ref->test << endl;
}
```

This is what I am doing in main:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestClass *testObj = new TestClass(1);
    cout << "test before: " << testObj->test << endl;
    testFunction1(testObj);
    cout << "test after: " << testObj->test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting output to be:

```
test before: 1
test in testFunction1: 2
test after: 1
```

But I get the following output:

```
test before: 1
test in testFunction1: 2
test after: 2
```

Can someone explain this. Interesting thing is that changing testFunction1 to:

```
void testFunction1(TestClass *ref){
    //delete ref;
    TestClass *locTest = new TestClass();
    ref = locTest;
    ref->test = 2;
    cout << "test in testFunction1: " << ref->test << endl;
}
```

i.e. I do not delete ref before pointing it to new location, I get the following output:

```
test before: 1
test in testFunction1: 2
test after: 1
```

I would really appreciate if someone can explain me this strange behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access the object after deleting it, the behaviour is undefined.

The behaviour that you see follows from the memory allocation algorithm in your system.

That is after deleting your first testclass object, you allocate memory for a new object. The runtime simply reuses the memory.

To check what is going on, print the values of the pointers:

```
void testFunction1(TestClass *ref){
    cout << ref << endl;
    delete ref;
    TestClass *locTest = new TestClass();
    cout << locTest << endl;
    ref = locTest;
    ref->test = 2;
    cout << "test in testFunction1: " << ref->test << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You get a copy of the pointer to the object in `testFunction1()`, so when you assign to it, the original value of the pointer in `main()` does not change

Also, you are deleting the object (by calling `delete` in `testFunction1()`) to which the original pointer (in `main()`) is pointing, but as the value in `main()` is not updated, you are accessing an invalid object -- the fact that you can read the value that you set in `testFunction1()`, is a coincidence and cannot be relied on

The fact that you correctly read the original value in the second case (when you don't call `delete`) is because the original object has not been changed (you change a new one in `testFinction1` and the pointer to it in `main` is the same (as explained above) and the object is still alive

Comment: Exactly, and the memory leak is in the testFunction1() since you dont ever get the address of the newly created memory outside off the function.

Comment: but why does value of pointer in main get updated from 1 to 2 if we are passing a copy to testFunction1()

Comment: @umair: It's undefined behavior.  You have no right to any expectations.

Comment: @umair The value of the pointer does not change. You are thinking of the pointer as if it was the object. Imagine you had 3 buckets full of water. Your pointer points at bucket 2. Now you empty and refil bucket 2 with oil (testFunction1). Now when you get the bucket pointed to by your original pointer you get oil not water.

Comment: @sji - except in `testFunction1` the OP creates a new "bucket", so you still get "water", not "oil" (when the original "Bucket" is not destroyed, that is)

Comment: @Attila Perhaps it was not clear, In my example the buckets are analogous to system memory (The heap in this case), which is never deleted or changed (exept perhaps the amount your program has avalible to it). The op empties the bucket pointed to by `ref`, then fills the bucket pointed to by `locTest`. The fact that these two (might) point to the same bucket explains his behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

in this case , you just got the new object at the same address with the old one you delete.

actually testObj became a dangling pointer after you call testFunction1.

```
void testFunction1(TestClass *ref){
    delete ref;
    TestClass *locTest = new TestClass();
    cout << "locTest = " << locTest << endl;
    ref = locTest;
    ref->test = 2;
    cout << "test in testFunction1: " << ref->test << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    TestClass *testObj = new TestClass(1);
    cout << "test before: " << testObj->test << endl;
    cout << "testObg = " << testObj << endl;
    testFunction1(testObj);
    cout << "test after: " << testObj->test << endl;
    cout << "testObg = " << testObj << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is :

```
test before: 1
testObg = 0x511818
locTest = 0x511818
test in testFunction1: 2
test after: 2
testObg = 0x511818
```

Answer (score 1):

After this instruction:

```
TestClass *testObj = new TestClass(1);
```

you have allocated a new memory area containing a `TestClass` object, whose address (let's call it `maddr`) is stored into `testObj`.

Now, this instruction:

```
cout << "test before: " << testObj->test << endl;
```

outputs `1`, as expected.

Inside `testFunction1()` you have a local variable called `ref`, which is a pointer containing the value `maddr`.

When you `delete ref`, you deallocate the area of memory containing a `TestClass` object, whose address is `maddr`.

Then you allocate a new memory area:

```
TestClass *locTest = new TestClass();
```

and `locTest` contains its address, let's call it `m1addr`.

Then you use `ref` to access the memory area at `m1addr` and change the `int test` value to `2`.

This instruction:

```
cout << "test in testFunction1: " << ref->test << endl;
```

outputs `2` as expected.

Now, back to `main`, you have lost any handler to the area containing a `TestClass` object whose address is `m1addr` (that is, you are leaking memory) and the area pointed to by `testObj` is not allocated anymore.

When you use `testObj` again, you access an area of memory starting at `maddr`, which has been cleaned. The effect of accessing `testObj->test` is undefined behavior.

What you experience could be do to the fact that when you run your code `maddr == m1addr`, but this can only happen by chance, you cannot rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are the new object (with a 2) is being created where the old deleted object (with a 1) used to be. Your original pointer still points to that location so when you access it you accidentally access the new object (with a 2).

Answer (score 0):

TestClass *ref in the parameter to testFunction1 and TestClass *testObj in main are 2 different pointers to the same thing, they are not the same pointer though. If you want to delete and reallocate an object inside a function/method you can  use a pointer to a pointer as the parameter.

As others have mentioned , after testfunction1 you're accessing an object that was deleted within testfunction1 which as also mentioned is undefined behaviour. The memory being pointed to by the dangling pointer was released during the delete but the contents are likely to still be there until the memory location is reallocated during another call to new. So you are using unallocated space that could be overwritten very easily at anytime.

Hope this helps